# Derive inverse Laplace Transform using two given trigonometric transforms (5.2-13)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, laplace-transform

I am not certain how to begin this problem. Someone please point me in the right direction.

**Problem**

Using the two given formulas ($1$ and $2$ below) show that:

$$L^{-1}\{\frac{1}{(s^2+\omega^2)^2}\}=\frac{1}{2\omega^3}(\sin(\omega t)-\omega t\cos(\omega t))$$

The given formulas:

$$L_1\{t\cos(\omega t)\}=\frac{s^2-\omega^2}{(s^2+\omega^2)^2}, L_2\{t\sin(\omega t)\}=\frac{2\omega s}{(s^2+\omega^2)^2} $$

Comment: Don't you have any other rules, like multiplication by $t$, differentiation or so available? It seems hard to get what you want using _only_ the formulas 1 and 2.

Comment: We may use any other math rules not beyond the complexity of this level of math which are not iterative or series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We write
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(s^2+\omega^2)^2}&=\frac{1}{2\omega^2}\frac{2\omega^2}{(s^2+\omega^2)^2}
=\frac{1}{2\omega^2}\Bigl[\frac{\omega^2-s^2+\omega^2+s^2}{(s^2+\omega^2)^2}\Bigr]\\
&=-\frac{1}{2\omega^2}\frac{s^2-\omega^2}{(s^2+\omega^2)^2}+\frac{1}{2\omega^2}\frac{1}{s^2+\omega^2}\\
&=-\frac{1}{2\omega^2}\frac{s^2-\omega^2}{(s^2+\omega^2)^2}+\frac{1}{2\omega^3}\frac{\omega}{s^2+\omega^2}\\
\end{align}
$$
The first part is the Laplace transform of $-\frac{1}{2\omega^2}t\cos(\omega t)$ according to your first formula.

Differentiating the second part (with respect to $s$), 
$$
\frac{d}{ds}\frac{1}{2\omega^3}\frac{\omega}{s^2+\omega^2} = -\frac{1}{2\omega^3}\frac{2\omega s}{(s^2+\omega^2)^2}
$$
Using that $\mathcal{L}(tf(t))=-F'(s)$ we find, using your second formula, that the second part is the Laplace transform of
$$
\frac{1}{2\omega^3}\sin(\omega t).
$$
Adding, we get
$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\frac{1}{(s^2+\omega^2)^2}\}=\frac{1}{2\omega^3}(\sin(\omega t)-\omega t\cos(\omega t))
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I am getting the hang of Laplace T's but this one had me so stumped I wasted hours on it with no avail.